# PagerView inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a Fragment fully occupied by a ScroolView. I added a ViewPager inside the layout in the ScrollView, like in this code:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.asdf.AFragment">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_linear_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:minHeight="100dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/meteo_placeholder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Meteo and others"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </FrameLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Begin"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            />


        <!--THIS IS NOT SHOWN-->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >


            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:id="@+id/title_strip_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        <!-- LAST TEXT VIEW -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="End"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But the ViewPager is not shown at all. I am sure it works because its adapter is used (I can see the call to **getItem()**, and the ViewPager alone works fine ). 
If I remove the last text view however, the ViewPager is shown, but the ScrollView is not scrollable at all, and all the LinearLayout' contents are restricted to the screen height, like if there was no ScrollView

Comment: Create a custom component extending `ScrollView` and in the `onInterceptTouchEvent` ignore the horizontal touch events.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried what you said but it does not work
The problem is that the **ViewPager** is not shown

Comment: try changing your ScrollView `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `wrap_content` I once did the same layout and it worked ok...

Comment: same result.
Plus, if I leave only the scrollview and the viewpager, and i put       `android:layout_height="wrap_content" ` in the scrollview, the viewpager is still not shown

Comment: Eventually I wrapped the **ViewPager** inside a **FrameLayout** with a `layout_height="400dp". It works fine for me, but it is not a solution

Comment: Just check if you have height defined in the fragments in your viewpager, instead of match_parent.